# Google location awareness problems over corporate network

Tags: google, geolocation

Not sure the best place for this one, so feel free to migrate to a more appropriate location if one exists.

OK so the situation is: We have a corporate network, joining sites in the UK, France, Poland and India via MPLS, supplied by Redstone (London).

Sat here in Derby UK, google thinks i'm in poland! I get polish adwords, polish google home page default, shows all locations as poland in analytics, and it defaults to poland on goole maps!

This happens for any computer on the network. This didnt happen before Poland was added to the network in the summer.

I thought maybe the MPLS was going out via poland somehow (as there seem to be multiple routs out to the internet from the mpls cloud. However doing a local "what's my IP" it shows our local external IP as a derby address, which is correct.

So how can i start troubleshooting this? tracert doesnt really tell me much of use...

Comment: @dan - Ive asked on the main stack exchange but got nothing - I think thats too busy now, many questions get lost. 
Network engineering is probably more appropriate than server fault i would have thought...

Comment: Are you the network engineer for the company?

Comment: @pauska - no I'm web dev / server tech, but they cant figure it out either...

Comment: And what does http://www.geoiptool.com/ tell you?

Comment: @pauska - that shows London! (which makes sense as Redstone's main gateway is there)